# How to send keypress to a console application

Tags: delphi

Im running a windowed application, which uses a console application (FFMPEG). The console has no window, its "hidden", my application shows its output - Im using this library http://wiki.delphidabbler.com/index.php/Docs/TPJConsoleApp

the problem is, the console application needs to be stopped by a keypress - how to send this keypress to it? I do know its process ID. I tracked down its hWnd with `EnumWindows()` still no effect on `PostMessage (hWnd, WM_CHAR, ord('q'), 0);`

Then how?

Comment: Have you tried writing on the standard input of the process?

Comment: if I run this program outside, it works... but it doesnt even react on WM_QUIT message. I found its window handle... how to make the inner program to halt? If i get a quit indication...

Comment: so "SendMessage(Wnd, WM_CHAR, dword('q'), 0);" worked when FFMPEG run outside. But inside, its not OK

Comment: even "TerminateThread()" cant kill it.

Comment: I'm confused. You first say that you are trying to send input, but then call TerminateThread. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

Alternate approach, if you don't mind whacking the process.
Use pskill by sysinternals. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx
execute pskill   and it'll be gone.

Comment: Why invoke a different process? Just kill the process using Win32 API calls.